# Has World Health Organization provided nutrition/diet/exercise guidelines to strengthen the human immune system for better responding to COVID-19?

Tags: covid-19, immune-system, virus, prevention, who-world-health-org

Medical sciences is not my subject but my personal feeling is that:

- A strengthen immune system can better respond to viruses than a weak immune system.
- A balanced diet in combination with exercise and adequate sun-light exposure strengthens the human immune system.

Is any of the above assumptions questionable?

If not, shouldn't the WHO provide any such guidelines (aside the virus-spread elimination guidelines) to better shield people (mainly elder ones) against COVID-19 infection or negative-effects of it?

I have not heard of any such guidelines (at least in Europe), but if there are, can you please provide the corresponding links?

Answer (score 3):

### There are guidelines actually:

#### In the [Campains](http://www.emro.who.int/noncommunicable-diseases/campaigns/campaigns.html) section there are the following links:

**[Feeding babies and young children during the COVID-19 outbreak
April 2020](http://www.emro.who.int/noncommunicable-diseases/campaigns/feeding-babies-and-young-children-during-the-covid-19-outbreak.html)**

> Proper nutrition is vital in the first two years of a child's life. It helps to:
>      - ensure healthy growth
>      - **strengthen the immune system**
>      - improve cognitive development
>      - Reduce the risk of getting ill with infectious and chronic
>    deseases.

**[Breastfeeding advice during COVID-19
March 2020](http://www.emro.who.int/noncommunicable-diseases/campaigns/breastfeeding-advice-during-the-covid-19-outbreak.html)**

> [...] Breastfeeding is particularly effective against infectious deseases because **it strengthens the immune system** by transfering atibodies from you

**[Nutrition for adults during COVID-19
March 2020](http://www.emro.who.int/noncommunicable-diseases/campaigns/nutrition-for-adults-during-covid-19.html)**

> Eat a well-balenced diet everyday to get the vitamins, minerals, dietary fibre, protein and antioxidants your body needs to be healthier with a **stronger immune system** and to lower your risk of chronic illnesses and infectious deseases.

#### In the [technical guidance](http://www.euro.who.int/en/health-topics/health-emergencies/coronavirus-covid-19/technical-guidance) section also:

**[Food and nutrition tips during self-quarantine](http://www.euro.who.int/en/health-topics/health-emergencies/coronavirus-covid-19/technical-guidance/food-and-nutrition-tips-during-self-quarantine2)**

> [...]Good nutrition is crucial for health, particularly in times when **the immune system might need to fight back**
>   [...]Alcohol is not only a mind-altering and dependence-producing substance, harmful at any level consumed, but it also **weakens the immune system**

**[Stay physically active during self-quarantine](http://www.euro.who.int/en/health-topics/health-emergencies/coronavirus-covid-19/technical-guidance/stay-physically-active-during-self-quarantine2)**

> [...]Staying at home for prolonged periods of time can pose a significant challenge for remaining physically active. Sedentary behaviour and **low levels of physical activity can have negative effects on the health**, well-being and quality of life of individuals. Self-quarantine can also cause additional stress and challenge the mental health of citizens. **Physical activity and relaxation techniques can be valuable tools to help you remain calm and continue to protect your health during this time.**
>
> WHO recommends 150 minutes of moderate-intensity or 75 minutes of vigorous-intensity physical activity per week, or a combination of both.[...]

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about the WHO, but this article might help in Sports Medicine

[The Challenge of Maintaining Metabolic Health During a Global Pandemic](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s40279-020-01295-8)

Comment: Welcome to Medical Sciences! Thanks for your answer but we require answers to be more than just a link. You need to answer the question in your own words and use quotes from the site you're referencing to support them.